# Inject service based on dynamic value in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-3.4

I have 2 services, `BlueWorkerService` and `YellowWorkerService`, both implementing the same interface, `WorkerServiceInterface`. Each of these services use the same entities but with different required logic.

I need to inject one of, but not both, of these classes and use them in `ProcessorService` so that the interface methods are called using on correct Worker. Which worker service to use is dependent on which Worker is currently being processed. I'll break it down:

```
Class WorkerProcessor {

  private $workerService;

  public function __construct(WorkerServiceInterface $workerServiceInterface)
  {
    $this->workerService = $workerServiceInterface;
  }

  public function getMixedColourWithRed() {
    return $this->workerService->mixWithRed();
  }
}
```

The worker service that is being used would be based on whether the worker being processed has the `colour` property of `Blue` or `Yellow`.

I know I can probably use a Factory to achieve this [as described here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/factories.html) but my problem is how to tell the factory which Worker colour I am processing?

Running on Symfony **3.4**

If you need more info, just ask and I will update the question.

Comment: You need Strategy pattern, not Factory.

Comment: Can you not injject BlueWorkerService  instead of WorkerServiceInterface ?

Comment: @GasKa Can you please explain further?
@DylanKas As the question states, this is to be dynamic. Each time the processor is called it could be using different instances of `WorkerServiceInterface`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: I'm using Symfony 4.3.1. I'll post it like that, then I'll help you to move all code from this architecture to Symfony 3.4.

I'm using a similar concept to load different classes in my project. Let me explain first, then I'll add code under this text.

Firstly, I'm loading a custom compiler pass under `src/Kernel.php` (your file is `app/AppKernel.php`):

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->addCompilerPass(new BannerManagerPass());
}
```

`BannerManagerPass` its created under `src/DependencyInjection/Compiler` (in your case should be src/BUNDLE/DependencyInjection/Compiler`).

```
class BannerManagerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has(BannerManager::class)) {
            return;
        }

        $definition     = $container->findDefinition(BannerManager::class);
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('banner.process_banners');

        foreach (array_keys($taggedServices) as $id) {
            $definition->addMethodCall('addBannerType', [new Reference($id)]);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, this class should implement `CompilerPassInterface`. You can observe that I'm looking for specific services tagged as **banner.process_banners**. I'll show how I tagged services a little bit later. Then, I'm calling `addBannerType` method from `BannerManager`.

**App\Service\BannerManager.php:** (in your case src/BUNDLE/Service/BannerManager.php)

```
class BannerManager
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $bannerTypes = [];

    /**
     * @param BannerInterface $banner
     */
    public function addBannerType(BannerInterface $banner)
    {
        $this->bannerTypes[$banner->getType()] = $banner;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return BannerInterface|null
     */
    public function getBannerType(string $type)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($type, $this->bannerTypes)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->bannerTypes[$type];
    }

    /**
     * Process request and return banner.
     *
     * @param string  $type
     * @param Server  $server
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function process(string $type, Server $server, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->getBannerType($type)->process($request, $server);
    }
}
```

This class has a custom method (created by me) called `process()`. You can name it whatever you want it, but I think that's pretty verbose. All parameters are sent by me, so don't mind. You can send whatever you want.

Now we have our Manager and compiler pass is set. It's time to set our banner types (based on my example) and tag them!

My banner types are under **src/Service/Banner/Types** (in your case should be **src/BUNDLE/Service/WhateverYouWant/Type**. This does not matter! You can change it later from services.yaml).

These types are implementing my `BannerInterface`. It does not matter the code under the class in this instance. One more thing that I should warn you! You should see that under BannerManager, inside the `addBannerType()` I'm calling `$banner->getType()`. This is one method inherited from BannerInterface in my case and it has a unique string (in my example I have three banner types: small, normal, large). This method can have any name, but don't forget to update it as well in your manager.

We are almost ready! We should tag them, then we are ready to try them!

Go to your services.yaml and add these lines:

```
  App\Service\Banner\Types\:
    resource: '../src/Service/Banner/Types/'
    tags: [banner.process_banners]
```

Please see the tag!

Whatever I want to show a custom banner, I'm using a simple URL with $_GET where I keep my banner type, then I load it like this:

```
public function view(?Server $server, Request $request, BannerManager $bannerManager)
{
   ...

    return $bannerManager->getBannerType($request->query->get('slug'))->process($request, $server);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand how the compiler pass works. This is a good solution to my problem